# access the toolbar created in interface builder

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, xib

[image]

Is it possible to access and manipulate the toolbar **(See bottom of picture)** defined in interface builder in a corresponding viewcontroller?

Comment: Those are Simulated Metrics as state in title, they are only displayed in the interface builder. It is to let you see what your view looks like if it is contained in for example an `UInavigationController`

Comment: Correct you are, my misstake! thanks. I did not realise that the toolbar was created programmatically. Post your answer if you want and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are Simulated Metrics as state in title, they are only displayed in the interface builder. It is to let you see what your view looks like if it is contained in for example an `UInavigationController`.

Answer (score 0):

u can set **IBOutlet** of **toolbar** then u can access and manipulate

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar     *toolBar;
```

**how u can connect ?**

I did a combination of the things in this thread and I finally had success.

In Interface builder (not xcode)

```
File->Reload All Class Files
File->Read Class Files (select MyClass.h)
Reconnect File's Owner by
a. Setting the Class to "MyClass"
b. Reconnecting the View to the File's Owner's View
```

Everything is back to normal now.

Comment: I do not have that option when it is created this way